# Can an OSGi fragment bundle publish a declarative service?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, declarative-services

I have a fragment bundle that I created to access some add functionality to a second-party jar. My fragment should register a service to expose this new functionality. It doesn't seem to work. Before I get deep into troubleshooting, I'd like to know if this is even allowed? That is, does Felix SCR's bundle watcher look at or ignore fragments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aha, I found the answer myself in the spec, section 112.4.2: "A Service-Component manifest header specified in a fragment is ignored by SCR." This is consistent with 3.14.3: "The following list contains the headers that must not be used in a fragment bundle: Bundle-Activator"

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592860/component-inside-a-fragment-never-activated, which confirms what you just  said, but with the added information that blueprint does work for fragments.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. But the host bundle must be open to this. By open, I mean the host bundle must have the `Service-Components` header configured such that any descriptors in the fragment will be found. For example:

```
Service-Components: OSGI-INF/*.xml
```

will find all `.xml` files in the `OSGi-INF/` folder of the host bundle all the attached fragments.

I saw Eclipse SmartHome project use this solution to make their UI more customizable.

More information: http://apache-felix.18485.x6.nabble.com/DS-amp-fragments-td5004610.html

Comment: Using header `Service-Component: OSGI-INF/*.xml` (not plural) is what worked for me.